# Working with two different Laravel applications, one is in sub domain and other one is in the main domain

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

I am working on a two different Laravel projects, with different database connections, but deployed on a same server:

- project 1 is in domain.com, `Main Domain`
- project 2 is in sub.domain.com.

Sessions for sub.domain.com are not being created on the browser, causing the site to throw `TokenMismatchException` if I send a request.

I've tried different approaches but I still got the same result.

Here's what i have tried:

domain's `config/session.php` and subdomain's

```
'domain' => null, // or '.domain.com', or 'domain.com'.
```

I also tried changing the session driver to:

```
'driver' => 'file', // 'database', and cookie
```

Nothing happened, the sub.domain.com was not persisting any session.

Here's a link to Laracast thread I've created 3 weeks ago, [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/session-is-not-persisting-on-server?page=1) that could help understanding my question:

Comment: it seems like a bug in laravel 5.0, because when i tried to upgrade my laravel version to 5.1, the problem is not showing anymore.